# Clicking a link doesn't not fire my script in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
        <div class="controls-buttons">
            <a id="level-1" href="#">1</a>
            <a id="level-12"href="#">12</a>
        </div>
```

and:

```
$('a#level-1').click(function () {
    alert("level-1");
    // all trs with level-1 class inside abc table
    $('tr.level-1').toggle();
});

$('a#level-12').click(function () {
    alert("level 12");
    // all trs with level-1 or level-2 class inside abc table
    $('tr.level-1, tr.level-2').toggle();
});
```

However when I click the links then there is no alert shows. Is there something wrong with the way I set this up?

Comment: Works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/CzUT4/. Please show a **complete example that exhibits the behavior you're seeing**. Have you checked for errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: I think what is happening is the code to make the alerts is appearing before the alert links are created. Is there some way that I can make this work even if the links are not yet there?

Answer (score 1):

if anchors are generated dynamically you should delegate the click event, try the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').on('click', 'a#level-1', function () {
        alert("level-1");
        $('tr.level-1').toggle();
    });
})
```

Comment: Where did the `table` come from? Why would this work if the OP's code doesn't?

Comment: 'cause this uses event delegation in case OP is adding content through ajax. The `tr`s imply there's a table.

Comment: There's nothing that indicates that the links would be inside a table.

Answer (score 0):

you should put your code in [$(document).ready(handler)](http://api.jquery.com/ready/), so that will attach events when DOM is fully loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a#level-1').click(function () {
      alert("level-1");
      // all trs with level-1 class inside abc table
      $('tr.level-1').toggle();
  });

  $('a#level-12').click(function () {
      alert("level 12");
      // all trs with level-1 or level-2 class inside abc table
      $('tr.level-1, tr.level-2').toggle();
  });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rbgt3/)